# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) - Assigning Variable

Tags: sql

Why am I not able to assign this variable? Keeps giving back this error message?

```
SET @sumTotalPrice = (
SELECT AirfareID, SUM(Seating + BaggagePrice + SportsEquipment + Airfare) FROM EZY_Airfare WHERE AirfareID = 2);


UPDATE EZY_Airfare SET NetPrice = @sumTotalPrice WHERE EZY_Airfare.AirfareID = 2;
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) I am skeptical that you need aggregation at all for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a variable?  And this is all from the same table, so I am guessing that you want this within one row.  That would suggest:

```
UPDATE EZY_Airfare
    SET NetPrice = (Seating + BaggagePrice + SportsEquipment + Airfare)
    WHERE EZY_Airfare.AirfareID = 2;
```

Note:  If you do this using a computed column, there is no need to ever worry about out-of-synch data again:

```
alter table EZY_Airfare add column netprice as
    (Seating + BaggagePrice + SportsEquipment + Airfare);
```

Comment: This sorted this completely. Was using variable because had used a SELECT SUM to display the total first and then used this variable to then assign it to net price but think will use your solution instead. Thanks